# HTML Newsletter Template

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter

I want to create a HTML Newsletter, but in Outlook the sent mail does not fit the CSS I wrote:

The following code has no affect in Outlook

```
body {
    font-family: verdana !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.overheader {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #e6007e;
    width: 100%;
}
.ce-bodytext {
    font-family: verdana !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

I tried using inline CSS, but to no avail:

```
<div class="wrapper content" style="width: 100%">
   <div class="design" style="width: 70%; margin: auto;">
```

What is the issue & how do I change the code so that the CSS and HTML work in browser, Outlook and as well as other web mailers?

Comment: Are you inlining your CSS? If not, that is your problem. You need to also keep in mind that Outlooks HTML engine is _horrendous_

Comment: I have the most stuff inline and in head ... this is inline: 
<div class="wrapper content" style="width:100%">
   <div class="design" style="width:70%; margin: auto;">

and not working

Comment: This: also has no effec:
<p><span style="font-weight: normal; font-family: verdana !important; font-size: 15px !important; line-height: 18px;">

Comment: It _all_ needs to be inline. You should be using tables for layout in emails. Yes, even in 2016. There are many, many guides on this ([example](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/about-html-email), [example](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/), [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use classes as more or less all email clients deletes the html head element along with all in it, such as script and style sheet links.

Here is how to achieve 100% main width with a centered 70% wide inner element, like your posted sample html, though here I used `table`'s, since that is the best/safest way to do layout for html mails, even in 2016.

```html
<table bgcolor="#aaa" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table bgcolor="#eee" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="70%">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 26px; font-family: arial">
               Some text...
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks^^ I can remember how that works 100years ago .. thought it would be better today ...